# How to get pip working on el capitan

Tags: python, ssl, pip, homebrew, osx-elcapitan

Ever since I've upgraded to El Capitan I can't seem to get pip to work. This is an example error message I get:

```
$ pip install --upgrade pip
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [Errno 2] No such file or directory - skipping
```

It sounds like I'm missing some certificates, but I'm woefully ignorant when it comes to ssl

Homebrew doesn't seem to install whatever might be missing, and downloading the python package from python.org didn't either.

Any help would be much appreciated!

If it helps: 
pip version - 8.1.2
python version - 2.7.12

Comment: please provide more information, such as the output of `pip --version`

Comment: 8.1.2 would be the version. To be clear, I don't really care about upgrading pip. My example was just that--an example.

I get the same error if I do `python get-pip.py` for what its worth.

Comment: try `easy_install pip`

Comment: Nope, same error after I ran easy_install. Given that the error message is saying "No such file or directory," I think I'm missing some sort of SSL cert--but I have no idea what I would need and where it would go.